# Can you change state of an IBAction button outside of its closure? - Swift 4

Tags: uibutton, swift4, ibaction, iboutlet

This is definitely NOT a duplicate of **Disable a Button**. I went through that several times with no success. In fact, I don't remember seeing `sender.enabled` there at all. I found that code in the Apple Developer's Forum.

Can you refer to an `IBAction` button by the sender argument and change its state from other places in your code? Changing the state of a button within the `IBAction` closure looks like: `sender.enabled = false` OR `sender.enabled = true` But I'm trying to change its state from within another function.

I know that it is possible to can change the state of an `IBOutlet` button from inside a different function like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!  
// then elsewhere in your code, within a method implementation:  
myButton.enabled = false
```

But is something like that possible with an `IBAction` button.

Comment: Of course you can change state `myButton.enabled = false` should work.

Comment: Not a duplicate.

Comment: I am trying to change the state of `sender.enabled` outside of the IBAction's closure, from within a different function.

Comment: You are misusing the word "closure".

Comment: I thought that a closure is anything in between "curly braces". If not, then please let me know how you would define a closure so I can learn?

Comment: @matt ... I'm open to learning sir, what is a real closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change `status` property when you want..

```
    @IBOutlet var BtnOne:UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var BtnTwo:UIButton!

    @IBAction func btnOnePressed (_ sender: Any) {
        print("BtnOne is disabled") 
        BtnOne.isEnabled = false // or true
        //you can call any func
        btnTwoPressed()
    }

    @IBAction func btnTwoPressed (_ sender: Any) {
        print("BtnOne is enabled")
        BtnOne.isEnabled = true
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer and I would upvote it if I was allowed to, but my "Reputation Points" are too low b/c I'm new to this site. Unfortunately, I was trying to achieve this without having to go back and create dozens of IBOutlets. I was hoping I could just use the `sender` object to change the state of the button.

Comment: After trying various things, adding `@IBOutlet`'s is apparently the best and possibly only option in order to acheive what I was trying to do. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is possible. You can send UIButton object to other function to achieve this.

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
     self.receiveEvent(sender: sender)
}

func receiveEvent(sender:UIButton) {
     sender.isEnabled = false
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Is it possible to change the state of `@IBAction func buttonAction` from within a different IBAction like - `@IBAction func startGame(_ sender: Any) {}`

Answer (score 1):

You're a bit confused about what `@IBAction` means.

It's a way to connect an action in storyboard - commonly `.touchUpInside` for a `UIButton` - to a function in your code. The `sender` parameter *becomes* the button that was tapped.

This code, for example:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
     // code here
}
```

can be assigned as the `.touchUpInside` action for many different buttons in your controller. Think of a set of buttons labeled 1 to 10. Connect each button to that `@IBAction`, and:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
     print("You tapped the button labeled: \(sender.currentTitle)")
}
```

If you have a reference to a button object, you *can* get the action assigned to it (assigned via code or via storyboard `@IBAction`) with the `actions(forTarget:forControlEvent:)` method, but that's rather complicated an probably not suitable.

As an example, though... Assuming you have a button in your view that is connected to the `@IBAction` shown above, you could do:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for v in view.subviews {
        if let b = v as? UIButton,
            let a = b.actions(forTarget: self, forControlEvent: .touchUpInside) {
            if a.contains("buttonTapped:") {
                print("Found button with buttonTapped: IBAction \(b)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll have a much easier time connecting your buttons to `@IBOutlet`s though (or to an `@IBOutlet Collection`. If your code is really trying to find a button (or buttons) connected to an `@IBAction`, you probably want to re-evaluate your code design.